# GTK load module failures for snap-installed app that runs fine otherwise

Tags: unity, gtk, snap

My snap-installed app is a wxWidgets application.  It runs fine after compilation and linkage, but it doesn't work once installed from a snap.  I'm assuming that when I type the name of my app, that perhaps 'snapd' goes and runs the wrapper under the `/snap/<myappname>/x1/` directory.  In any case, I get...

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
23:11:06: Error: Unable to initialize GTK+, is DISPLAY set properly?
```

My only guess is that not all dependencies are found and placed inside the `/snap/<mayappname>/x1/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` directory by snap install.  I tried to test this hypothesis in two ways.  First, by running out of the `prime` directory before installation, but the bug isn't reproducible there.  And second, by copying what I believed to be the needed libraries into the said directory, but it is read-only, even if I change the snapcraft confinement to `devmode` and use the `--devmode` flag during installation, and even if I try `chmod 777 .` as root for crying out loud.

If anyone is interested in taking a look at my stupid project, it can be cloned from...

http://github.com/spencerparkin/RubiksCube.git

The snapcraft.yaml file is configured to run off of scons.  I wouldn't try snapcrafting in the project root.  I copy the snapcraft.yaml file over to some other directory before trying that.

I've come a long way and feel so close to actually making this thing work...just one road-block after another...I suck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's take this appart as there are many issues here:

## Running from `prime`

When you run from `prime` straight of from your classic system you will see all the libraries your classic system has so it is not really the best way to do it. When run as a *snap* the root filesystem that is actually seen is, in this case, `ubuntu-core` or `core`.

In order to experience what the environment will feel like, it might be better to hop into a shell for that environment, you can do so by running:

```
snap run --shell <snap-name>.<app-name>
```

## Read only snap

Snaps when installed for an actual snap are a mount to a `squashfs`, this filesystem is read only and the reason you cannot write and make modifications to the installed snap.

During development it might be better to do from your project directory:

```
snap try prime [--devmode]
```

By doing so, you can make live edits to your `prime` directory to test out variations of things.

## Getting the app to launch

The module load warnings are not that bad, they happen on some snaps as well.
What is bad is that it cannot find a display.
To get started quickly there are desktop launchers that can get you bootstrapped pretty fast.

They are delivered as parts, to get a feel for how this works out with snapcraft, run

```
snapcraft update
snapcraft search desktop
```

And to see what one of these `parts` do, run

```
snapcraft define <part-name>
```

There is more information about desktop launchers available on https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/07/06/ubuntu-app-developer-blog-announcing-new-snap-desktop-launchers/

Comment: Thank you for your help; you've given me a lot to go on here.  I'll have to do some more work now with the direction you've given me.  Clearly I still have a lot to learn about snaps.

Comment: Thanks again.  I was able to add the desktop-gtk2 bootstrapper for my snap, and that worked.  Admittedly, there is a lot of "black magic" going on with all this snapping in the sense that...while I've gotten things to work, I still don't know exactly what I'm doing.  sigh...line upon line...precept upon precept.

Comment: To be fair, all this black magic is what distros generally do for you anyways :-)